# How does the hardfork combinator work?

Tags: blockchain

Naïvely one would think it's a mere version tag on the block. However, most other chains do not include a combinator. How does it work at the low level and why only Cardano has it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the inside view by Edsko de Vries, creator of the hardfork combinator, here: https://youtu.be/D8OTZULEsaI